# Groovy: generator of file with random nuber of lines

Tags: file, random, groovy, generator

I need to write a `Groovy` script to generate `.txt` files. Each file must contain lines like:

```
12:43:10  12345678  -49376952  
// time, variable1, variable2
```

First, how can I define a random number of lines ?

Second, how can I overwrite variables for each line depending on the number of lines?
I mean, say it will contain 3 lines, it must look like

```
time, variable1.1, variable2.1

time, variable1.2, variable2.2

time, variable1.3, variable2.3
```

I am a novice and I will be very glad to any advice!

Comment: I corrected a couple of spelling/format mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already done something smart: you've broken the problem into pieces. Decomposition is how problems are solved.

Have a look at Java's Random class.

You need more than a random number: you need one between 1 and some max value. How big can this text file be? Would a million lines be okay?

The time can be the time stamp when you write the row. How unique must it be?  Should you include hours, minutes, seconds,milliseconds, nanoseconds?

Are the variables random, too?  I don't know what you mean by overwrite.

This will do it in Java.  Perhaps it'll guide you for Groovy.  I wrote the output to the console; I'll leave figuring out how to write to a file as an exercise for you:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Demo of how to do it in Java
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 10/14/2015
 * Time: 7:38 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123709/groovy-generator-of-file-with-random-nuber-of-lines/33123830?noredirect=1#comment54060700_33123830
 */
public class RandomDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxLines = new Random().nextInt(15);
        int numVariables = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLines; ++i) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1024);
            long currentNanos = System.nanoTime();
            builder.append(currentNanos).append('\t');
            for (int j = 0; j < numVariables; ++j) {
                builder.append("variable-").append(i+1).append('.').append(j+1).append('\t');
            }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
Let max number of lines will be 15.
I can define time1, variable1 like $variables.no, variable2 like $variables.no2
where no gets random number

maybe it could be some loop, which will overwrite this variables for each line, but I don't know how to do this.. 
for example, it will be 5 lines
is it possible, that loop will take a map [time1, variable1, variable2] and will overwrite for 5 entries like

time2, variable1.2, variable2.2
time3, variable1.3, variable2.3
...
time5, variable1.5, variable2.5

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try to adapt code for groovy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible groovier approach. Note that because the execution is very fast the time will most likely be the same for each row.

```
int maxLines = new Random().nextInt(20)
def now
new File("myFile.txt").withWriter { out ->
    (1..maxLines).eachWithIndex{n, i ->
        now = new Date()
        out.println now.format("HH:mm:ss")+' variable1.'+(i+1)+' variable2.'+(i+1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Groovier still: `out.println "${new Date().format("HH:mm:ss")} variable1.${i+1} variable2.${i+1}"`

Comment: And even groovier still: `maxLines.times { i -> out.println "${new Date().format("HH:mm:ss")} variable1.${i+1} variable2.${i+1}" }`